# How did Planck integrate this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

How did Max Planck integrate this

$$\frac{dS}{dU}=\frac{1}{\nu} f\left(\frac{U}{\nu}\right)$$

in his paper "[On the Law of Distribution of Energy in the Normal Spectrum](http://strangepaths.com/files/planck1901.pdf)" (equation 10) ?

Comment: Via the chain rule.

Comment: The $f$ isn’t the same function. He uses $f$ throughout the paper to mean “some function” and it keeps changing.

Comment: If $S=f_1(U/\nu)$ then $dS/dU=(1/\nu)f_2(U/\nu)$ where $f_2(x)=f_1’(x)$.

Comment: He is making an argument about how the integral must be some function of $U/\nu$. At this point that function is not determined.

Comment: Planck wrote f as the same function not f(1) and f(2)

Comment: This is what happens when you try to read old papers. Obsolete conventions are confusing because we don’t write this way any more. As I have already explained, Planck is simply using $f(x)$ to mean “some function of $x$” and not “a particular function of $x$”. I recommend avoiding old papers. Modern expositions of Planck’s breakthrough are infinitely clearer.

Comment: Yup I agree. So you mean that the integral can't be determined and that he wrote it from his mind?

Comment: No that’s not what I mean. The next section derives $S$ as a *specific* function of $U/\nu$. But in section 9, he is only making an argument that $S$ is *some* function of the ratio $U/\nu$, and he concludes this from the dependence of the derivative on the same ratio. But the two $f$’s aren’t the same. The latter is the antiderivative of the former.

Comment: I’m sorry that I have not been able to explain it in a way that you can understand. I don’t have anything to add to what I have already said. Perhaps someone else will explain it better than I have.